# How to use the system pop gesture in a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios

I have a `UIScrollView` in a `UINavigationController`, but I find I can't use the system's pop gesture when I touch on the scrollView,how should I fix the conflict?

Comment: Be more specific, you want to pop back while clicking on scroll view?

Comment: @Wingzero ,no, generally it will trigger the pop action when I pan from the left edge of screen,but it's not worked if I add a scrollView reached the edge of the screen.

Comment: well you need to check which gesture recognizer is failing yours... you should give more details if you want people help you. UIScrollView has some gestures for zooming and scrolling, you can start from here to find out what recognizers are beeing recognized, and what failed.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed,the custom left navigation item causes this issue,I add the code

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
        }
```

but still not work in some situation, it should be modify like

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        }
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.class];
}
```